# Form model binding for polymorphic relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have set up a polymorphic relation where the table structure is like:

```
companies
    id - integer
    name - string

company_branches
    id - integer
    name - string

incharges
    id - integer
    name - string
    inchargable_id - integer
    inchargable_type - string
```

I have also set up the models accordingly and the data is saved correctly. The problem that I'm having is showing the data of the incharges table during editing by using model binding. The view for editing is like:

```
{!! Form::model($company, array("route" => array("companies.update", $company->id), "method"=>"PUT", "files"=>true)) !!} 

    <label>Company Name</label>
    <div>
      {!! Form::text('name') !!}
    </div>

    <label>Incharge Name</label>
    <div>
      {!! Form::text('incharge_name') !!}
    </div>        

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

The data that appears in the `name` text field while editing is correct. But how do I display the incharge name for editing? I can acess the incharge name by doing `$company->incharge->name`.

**EDIT:** In the `PersonInCharge` model, I have set up the polymorphic relation as:

```
public function inchargable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

In `Company` model:

```
public function incharge()
{
    return $this->morphOne('PersonInCharge', 'inchargable');
}
```

In `CompanyBranch` model:

```
public function incharge()
{
    return $this->morphOne('PersonInCharge', 'inchargable');
}
```

Comment: How are you passing the data from the controller?

Comment: Yes. If I do `echo $company->incharge->name` in the view, I can see the correct result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try, `{!! Form::text('incharge[name]') !!}`

Further more you need to (lazy)-eager-load your relation for the form model binding. You can use the `Model::with('realtion')` or set the `$with = ['relation']` property in your Eloquent model. More information about Laravel [(Lazy-)Eager-Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: @SUB0DH have you tried to (lazy)-eager-load your relation?

Comment: Eager loading the relation worked. Thanks for the help. I thought the eager loading would happen automatically while using the morph functions for polymorphism.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
{!! Form::text('incharge_name', $company->incharge->name) !!}
```

Add in a join to your controller in this fashion:

```
$company = Company::where('id',$companyID)
       ->leftJoin('incharges', 'inchargable_id.company_id', '=', 'company.id')
       ->first();
```

(need to use the correct fields though!)

Comment: This works but I need it to be done automatically via form model binding so that I won't have to do something like this.

Comment: I imagine you would need to "join" your incharges table in some fashion.. updated my answer with an untested idea...

Comment: Although your answer could be correct, it isn't the one that I'm looking for. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.